# Django Form Selection Change Value in URL

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Python 3.3.2, Django 1.6.5, Fedora 20

I have a Django form where I set the default selection from a value in the URL, and limit the queryset of another form based on that value.

For example:

URL:

http://fakesite.com/myapp/add_activity/?sport=run

Relevant views.py:

```
urlsport = Sport.objects.get(name = request.GET.get('sport'))
form.fields["sport"].initial = urlsport
form.fields["gear"].queryset = Gear.objects.filter(sport_id=urlsport)
```

I'd like to make it such that if the user selects a different sport, the URL will change/reload so my form.fields["gear"].queryset filter will get re-applied.

Any ideas how I can do this? Is this the right approach?

Comment: Use a named argument in your url to get the sport value.  Add sport to your list of arguments to your view

Comment: Not sure I follow. I can get the sport from the URL fine and use it where I need to. There is a dropdown menu on the page with a list of sports (default selection of what is in URL). If the user changes that to another selection, I'd like the URL to update because it also feeds other things.

Comment: If I understand you want to change url on dropdown, then you need to do Ajax